# Input string was not in a correct format.Can

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get row cell value from gridview,convert it to int32 and then assign it to model ID.. i get this error. anyone??

.cs delete button code

```
    protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            Button btn = sender as Button;
          --> Error Line-->>  int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(btn.Attributes["RowIndex"]);
            muser.ID = Convert.ToInt32(GVUsers.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Text);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = cUser.deleteUser(muser);
            fillGrid();

    }
```

I tried:

```
Int32.Parse(GVUsers.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Text);
```

but it didn't work..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `btn.Attributes["RowIndex"]` exactly? Can you debug your code and tell us?

Comment: it's value is 1. the selected row in grid..
sorry the error line is the below one from mentioned..

Comment: I don't think `GVUsers.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Text` is `1` because `Convert.ToInt32("1")` perfectly works.

Comment: it's value in Database is 1.. but when i make breakpoint.. it shows nothing.